# Can Adobe analytics variable be passed to a Google analytics custom dimension?

Tags: adobe, analytics

Does anyone know if it's possible to capture the variables from an Adobe Analytics implementation and pass them to GTM so that they can be used as custom dimensions in Google Analytics?

I was wondering if there was some javascript that i could implement in GTM that would extract the neccessary props i want from the adobe data layer, but im not a developer so im not even sure if this is possible.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This looks to me like exactly the guide you are looking for: 
http://blogs.perficient.com/adobe/2017/04/12/custom-adobe-analytics-tracking-using-google-tag-manager/

I don't have any personal experience with Adobe Analytics so I cannot help you further than that. However I can tell you what you are trying to achieve is most definitely possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely possible and not hard to pull off. There is even a google analytics tool than can be used for adobe dtm.

Just doing it manually through code, make sure that GA is already present on the page, and fire this code in a third party script after you AA variables are set.

```
ga('set', 'dimension1', value1);
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

You can set multiple dimensions at once:

```
ga('ehiglobal.set', {
    'dimension2': value2,
    'dimension3': value3,
    'dimension4': value4
});
```

You can also pass specific page names on the hit:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', location.pathname);
```

You can also send an event hit if you already have page views set up:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action', {
  'dimension5': value5
});
```

**Note: You need to send the data through a page view or a hit. Just setting the data wont do anything, so make sure you actually have one of the send events